# How to solve an equation on a given relation

Tags: equation-solving

I was wondering whether it was possible to solve a linear equation in two unknowns for a specified relation of the two unknowns, meaning that, given
$$x+y=\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma$$
I want to have $x+y$ on one side and everything else on the other side. Here, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ do not depennd on $x$ and $y$, in fact, they  can be treated as constants. I tried using `Solve` and `Collect` but it wouldn't give me what I wanted. For example

```
Collect[x + y == 3 + 2 x + 2 y + 38/a, {x + y}]
```

and many variations did not work.
I also tried

```
Solve[x + y == 3 + 2 x + 2 y + 38/a, {x,y}]
```

which somewhat gives me what I want, although I am looking for $x+y$ on one side. I do not know if this would work for harder equations, as I chose the above equation just for simplicity. Does anyone have any idea? Is there a function that achieves this?

Comment: You can introduce a new variable $z=x+y$. Next you replace $y$ with $z-x$. Then you can solve for $z$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for the example you posted. If you have a different example, where this does not work, will try to fix it. This checks that the combination of `a x + b y` can factor out to a common `x+y` term, otherwise it returns no solution.

```
solve[x_, y_, eq0_] := Module[{lhs, rhs, eq, cx, cy, sol = {}, z},
   rhs = eq0 /. (lhs_ == rhs_) :> rhs;
   lhs = eq0 /. (lhs_ == rhs_) :> lhs;
   eq = rhs - lhs == 0;
   cx = Last@CoefficientList[rhs - lhs, x];
   cy = Last@CoefficientList[rhs - lhs, y];
   If[cx == cy,
    sol = (x + y) /. (First@Solve[(eq /. (cx x + cy y) -> z), z] /. z -> ( x + y));
    sol = sol/cx
    ];
   x + y == sol
   ];
```

Now call it as

```
ClearAll[x, y, a];
eq = x + y == 3 + 2 x + 2 y + 38/a;
solve[x, y, eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq = x + y == 3 + 4 x + 4 y + 38/a;
solve[x, y, eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq = 2 x + y == 3 - 2 x - 3 y + 38/a;
solve[x, y, eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This returns no solution, since can't collect `x+y` into one term

```
eq = 2 x + y == 3 - 2 x - 1 y + 38/a;
solve[x, y, eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

To *solve* for `x+y` you can simply do:

```
x + y /. Solve[x + y == 3 + 2 x + 2 y + 38/a, {x, y}][[1]]
```

> -((38 + 3 a)/a)

To get an expression of the form `x + y == ...` you can use `Reduce` and post-process the output into desired form:

```
red = Reduce[{z == 3 + 2 x + 2 y + 38/a, z == x + y, a != 0}, z, {x, y}]
```

> a != 0 && z == (-38 - 3 a)/a

```
red /. { a != 0 -> True, z -> x + y}
```

> x + y == (-38 - 3 a)/a

Answer (score 0):

```
Eliminate[z == x + y == 3 + 2 x + 2 y + 38/a, {x, y}]
```

results in

```
z == -3 - 38/a && a != 0
```